# IndexError: list index out of range with api

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
all_currencies = currency_api('latest', 'currencies')  # {'eur': 'Euro', 'usd': 'United States dollar', ...}
all_currencies.pop('brl')
qtd_moedas = len(all_currencies)
texto = f'{qtd_moedas} Moedas encontradas\n\n'
moedas_importantes = ['usd', 'eur', 'gbp', 'chf', 'jpy', 'rub', 'aud', 'cad', 'ars']

while len(moedas_importantes) != 0:
    for codigo, moeda in all_currencies.items():
        if codigo == moedas_importantes[0]:
            cotacao, data = currency_api('latest', f'currencies/{codigo}/brl')['brl'], currency_api('latest', f'currencies/{codigo}/brl')['date']
            texto += f'{moeda} ({codigo.upper()}) = R$ {cotacao}   [{data}]\n'
            moedas_importantes.remove(codigo)
            if len(moedas_importantes) == 0: break  # WITHOUT THIS LINE, GIVES ERROR
```

Why am I getting this error? the list actually runs out of elements, but the code only works with the if

Comment: what error? please clarify your question and what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested loop. The while loop is entered and then execution immediately starts in the for loop. Execution remains in the for loop for all elements in `all_currencies.items()`. Each time `codigo` is found at the beginning of `moedas_importantes`, that element is removed. Eventually you remove all elements from `moedas_importantes`, but you are still in the for loop and check `if codigo == moedas_importantes[0]`. At this point `moedas_importantes` is empty so you get an index error.

I think the below code will work without the nested loops. Note, this assumes all elements in `moedas_importantes` are also keys in `all_currencies`.

```
all_currencies = currency_api('latest', 'currencies')  # {'eur': 'Euro', 'usd': 'United States dollar', ...}
all_currencies.pop('brl')
qtd_moedas = len(all_currencies)
texto = f'{qtd_moedas} Moedas encontradas\n\n'
moedas_importantes = ['usd', 'eur', 'gbp', 'chf', 'jpy', 'rub', 'aud', 'cad', 'ars']

while len(moedas_importantes) != 0:
    codigo = moedas_importantes[0]
    moeda = all_currencies[codigo]
    cotacao, data = currency_api('latest', f'currencies/{codigo}/brl')['brl'], currency_api('latest', f'currencies/{codigo}/brl')['date']
    texto += f'{moeda} ({codigo.upper()}) = R$ {cotacao}   [{data}]\n'
    moedas_importantes.remove(codigo)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!! now i understand well. Your solution was even more efficient, it took +- 10% less time to do the same